# ABUnknownPersonViewController crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, abaddressbook

Im using this code to show an ABUnknowPersonViewController for showing a record from a person which was created from a vCard String:

```
- (ABRecordRef)person {
    if (person == NULL) {
        ABPersonCreator *creator = [[ABPersonCreator alloc] initWithVcardString:vcardString];

        person = creator.person;
        CFRetain(person);

        [creator release];  
    }

    return person;
}

- (UIView *)fullscreenView {
    unknownPersonController = [[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init];

unknownPersonController.displayedPerson = self.person;
    unknownPersonController.allowsAddingToAddressBook = YES;
    unknownPersonController.allowsActions = YES;
    unknownPersonController.unknownPersonViewDelegate = self;
    return unknownPersonController.view;
}
```

Can someone help me out with this?

thx Philip

Comment: Can you show your crash logs ?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception    'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem for me was that I wasn't passing the right stuff when building the ABRecordRef.  For instance, I tried to simply set a string to a property when it instead wanted a kABMultiStringPropertyType.  The exception would only occur after trying to launch the UnknownPersonViewController.

Check your datatypes and make sure that you're building the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't have unknownPersonViewController have an autorelease, as it's view's returned?

Comment: If i do this the view will be empty

Comment: are you using synthesized member for person? I've stumbled across a similar view problem recently, but didn't get around to it. what you could try just for debugging is not to return the controller's view but the controller itself.

Comment: Im not using a synthesized member for person. Im sorry I need to return the view so I can't test this.

Comment: ok. have you stepped through? if you have synthesized, I think you should use self.person

Comment: I stepped through it and it crashes when the view controller gets pushed by a parent navigation controller. If person = NULL there will be a empty ABUnknownPersonViewController so I think it must have something to do with the displayedPersonProperty.